# Use dom4j to locate the node with line number

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, dom4j

I used **dom4j** to parse a xml file and I got a document with line numbers, I want to use the line numbers to locate all nodes with line numbers and to operate these nodes.

Is there a way to use dom4j or other DOM API to implement this?

Comment: locating nodes by line numbers seems not to be a good idea, you always should parse specific nodes; imagine what would happen if someone changes the xml file

Comment: The idea is I have a checker that could check the errors of this xml file(in fact is a xmi file), and return back an error list with line numbers. So I could make a foreach loop, use the line number to locate and to fix the specific nodes.

Comment: you could use an id as attribute for each node and return a list of id's
which should be fixed; then access the nodes in your loop over the id's

Comment: or your checker could set an attribute in your nodes, to flag it for fixing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to extend DOM4J to include line numbers for element, but it is a bit convoulted, and not 100% exact (you can get the line number of the  ">" character of the opening element).

Probably, a much more robust approach would be to report an XPath expression for each of the offending elements, and then use these expressions to fix it.

However, just for fun, here is a complete example of how to include line number information in DOM4J:

```
public class LineNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SAXReader reader = new MySAXReader();
        reader.setDocumentFactory(new LocatorAwareDocumentFactory());

        Document doc = reader
                .read(new StringReader("<root foo='bar' > \n<alfa/>\n<beta/>\n<gamma/>\n</root>\n"));
        doc.accept(new VisitorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void visit(Element node) {
                System.out.printf("%d: %s\n",
                        ((LocationAwareElement) node).getLineNumber(),
                        node.getName());
            }
        });

    }

    static class MySAXReader extends SAXReader {

        @Override
        protected SAXContentHandler createContentHandler(XMLReader reader) {
            return new MySAXContentHandler(getDocumentFactory(),
                    getDispatchHandler());
        }

        @Override
        public void setDocumentFactory(DocumentFactory documentFactory) {
            super.setDocumentFactory(documentFactory);
        }

    }

    static class MySAXContentHandler extends SAXContentHandler {

        private Locator locator;

        // this is already in SAXContentHandler, but private
        private DocumentFactory documentFactory;

        public MySAXContentHandler(DocumentFactory documentFactory,
                ElementHandler elementHandler) {
            super(documentFactory, elementHandler);
            this.documentFactory = documentFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public void setDocumentLocator(Locator documentLocator) {
            super.setDocumentLocator(documentLocator);
            this.locator = documentLocator;
            if (documentFactory instanceof LocatorAwareDocumentFactory) {
                ((LocatorAwareDocumentFactory)documentFactory).setLocator(documentLocator);
            }

        }

        public Locator getLocator() {
            return locator;
        }
    }

    static class LocatorAwareDocumentFactory extends DocumentFactory {

        private Locator locator;

        public LocatorAwareDocumentFactory() {
            super();
        }

        public void setLocator(Locator locator) {
            this.locator = locator;
        }

        @Override
        public Element createElement(QName qname) {
            LocationAwareElement element = new LocationAwareElement(qname);
            if (locator != null)
                element.setLineNumber(locator.getLineNumber());
            return element;
        }

    }

    /**
     * An Element that is aware of it location (line number in) in the source document
     */
    static class LocationAwareElement extends DefaultElement {

        private int lineNumber = -1;

        public LocationAwareElement(QName qname) {
            super(qname);
        }

        public LocationAwareElement(QName qname, int attributeCount) {
            super(qname, attributeCount);

        }

        public LocationAwareElement(String name, Namespace namespace) {
            super(name, namespace);

        }

        public LocationAwareElement(String name) {
            super(name);

        }

        public int getLineNumber() {
            return lineNumber;
        }

        public void setLineNumber(int lineNumber) {
            this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code you showed is to add a line number in each node as an attribute. My idea based on your code, is to build a map, which stores lineNum as key and node as value. That's we could get a node by lineNum in this map.

Comment: Just note that you can have more than one element per line, so the map would have to med multi-valued

Comment: Yes, I concerned about that, so I added the lineNum and colNum as well, to locate the node. The idea works!!!! Merci ! So about that I can not vote for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your checker could set an attribute in your node, to flag it for fixing.
This would be an alternative for reading the file lines. Afterwards just look for nodes with this specific attribute and refactor it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <test>okay</test>
    <test>good</test>
    <test>error</test>
</tests>
```

now parse the xml file and mark the last test node to be fixed

```
public void parse(){

    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    DocumentFactory documentFactory = DocumentFactory.getInstance();
    Document document = reader.read("test.xml");
    Element root = document.getRootElement();

    for (Iterator<Element> iterator = root.elementIterator();iterator.hasNext();){
        Element element = iterator.next();

        //check for your error and set fix flag, if not already happend 

        if(element.getText().equals("error") && 
           element.attributeValue("todo") == null) {

           Attribute fix = documentFactory.createAttribute(element, "todo" ,"fix");
            element.add(fix);
        }
    }

    // update xml file

    XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(new FileWriter("test.xml"));
    xmlWriter.write(document);
    xmlWriter.close();
}
```

output xml

```
enter <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <test>okay</test>
    <test>good</test>
    <test todo="fix">error</test>
</tests>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This maybe an idea. Although it's not exactly what I what, it gives me a hint.